# Save and load state of Segmented Controler

Tags: ios, objective-c, load, save, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to be able to have the user to select one of the segments and when they load that viewcontroller back up, the one they chose will be select. At default I have "Black" Selected but if they choose "White" and then close they app, reopen it "White will then be selected.

Here is the code I have for the Segmented Controller for the first storyboard:

```
- (IBAction)ChangeLook:(id)sender {

    if (backgroundColour.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhoneStoryboard4inch-White"
                                                                 bundle: nil];
        MainMenuView_4inch_White *second = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainMenuView_4inch-White"];
        [self presentViewController:second animated:NO completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"White Selected");

    }

    if (backgroundColour.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {

        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhoneStoryboard4inch"
                                                                 bundle: nil];
        MainMenuView_4inch *second = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainMenuView_4inch"];
        [self presentViewController:second animated:NO completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"Black Selected");

    }
}
```

Here is the code I have for the Segmented Controller for the second storyboard:

```
- (IBAction)ChangeLook:(id)sender {

    if (backgroundColour.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhoneStoryboard4inch-White"
                                                                 bundle: nil];
        MainMenuView_4inch_White *second = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainMenuView_4inch-White"];
        [self presentViewController:second animated:NO completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"White Selected");

    }

    if (backgroundColour.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {

        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhoneStoryboard4inch"
                                                                 bundle: nil];
        MainMenuView_4inch *second = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainMenuView_4inch"];
        [self presentViewController:second animated:NO completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"Black Selected");

     }
}
```

I also have possibly one piece that might help :

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[backgroundColour selectedSegmentIndex]] forKey:@"whiteBackground"];
```

I know this doesn't save or load it but it may help someone help me with the answer.
So I need to save the option chosen for both view controllers.

*** EDIT ***

I have this game and I want it to colour match the user's device or just for more choice. So I have two storyboards, one with the black background and one with the white background. In both storyboard, in the main menu I have a Segmented Control with the option to change the colour. Let's say I want to have the white background then close the app and later on open it back up, I want the option they selected to appear (using the segmented control). Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Try, [defaults synchronize]; after setting the object.

Comment: I put this in my code but it still is not saving or loading, I still need to code to do that. Code I don't have so thats why I have come here :)

Comment: are you fetch by this code, [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"whiteBackground"]

Comment: Could you put these comments into an answer? I think it might be what I need

Answer (score 0):

Fetch value,

```
NSInteger *segmentIndex = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"whiteBackground"];
    if(segmentIndex  == 0)
    {
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhoneStoryboard4inch-White"
                                                                 bundle: nil];
        MainMenuView_4inch_White *second = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainMenuView_4inch-White"];
        [self presentViewController:second animated:NO completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"White Selected");
    }
```

Store value,

```
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[backgroundColour selectedSegmentIndex]] forKey:@"whiteBackground"];
```

Comment: Is it possible to explain all of this or when to put it? Not having much luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you are doing...
It seems you have two different storyboard or something like it. But you want just to select the second segment of a UISegmentedControl ?

Then just by having only one storyboard, with one view controller. You link with an outlet your UISegmentedControl, then you set the `mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0 // Or 1`... ?

It seems you try to do something very simple but use huge things for it.

EDIT after your EDIT :

Do this then,

```
- (IBAction)ChangeLook:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([defaults valueForKey:@"whiteBackground"] == 1) {
    ...// Use white storyboard
    }
    else {
    ...// Use normal storyboard
    }
}
```

Comment: Got this error: Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC on the [defaults valueForKey:@"whiteBackground"] == 1)

Comment: Sorry, my fault : `if ([[defaults valueForKey:@"whiteBackground"] intValue] == 1)...`

Comment: Ok no error, let me run it and I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Code is all good, just when the app loads, it loads the black storyboard first then when i click the white segment it loads it but when i double click the home button then close the app, load it back up, it loads the black background again, not the white.

Comment: The appdelegate? Why there, How would i implement that? Just a tad bit confused on what needs to go where

Comment: In your files (of code) you should have one somewhere, named "MyProjectAppDelegate" MyProject is name of your project.
Then in this file (the .m one) you have functions that are called at launch of application and also when you wake it up from background etc.

If you have difficulties with it, because we won't do a course over there, I strongly advise you to learn the basics of iOS on Apple : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AppArchitecture/AppArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW1

Comment: nonono, i know what it is. im saying, why put it there, what part do i puut it in?

Comment: `if ([defaults valueForKey:@"whiteBackground"] == 1) {
    ...// Use white storyboard
    }
    else {
    ...// Use normal storyboard
    }`
To load the good storyboard from the whole beginning

Comment: Ok but I need to use the segment control to get the users choice. Does the code go in both the ViewController.m and the AppDelegate?

Comment: I need to be able to give the user's an option on which color before i can set it in appdelegate i think. Is there another way of saving the state of the segment control? This way doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: If the variable is not set, then your default template will be black one. So yes, both place it will work.

Comment: Yes the deafult template is the black one. How can i set it?

Comment: Sorry I'm not supposed to code your application for you. First it's another question, second you should really read more the Apple documentation to enhance your knowledge.